# chart.js version 2.4.0 does not display bars for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to display a simple bar chart using chart.js 2.4.0  (the most recent version). I've followed two tutorials and do not see what I am doing wrong.  The grid displays,  but the bars do not.  It's as if it is not seeing the data set data at all.

I've simplified the page, so at this point it is only loading jquery-2.1.4.min.js before the 2.4.0 Chart.bundle.min.js.  No other js library is loaded.

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="scorecard_results1" class="scorecard_results" >
<div id="holder1"></div>
<canvas id="bargraph1"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
  var ctx = document.getElementById("bargraph1");
  console.log("id is " + ctx.id);
  var bargraph = new Chart(ctx,  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      dataSets : [{  
        label: "test",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: "#333"
      } ]
    } 
  });
</script>
</div>
```

As you can see, it is basically copied directly from the Chart.js example in the documentation.  I've googled but have not found anything helpful.  It should just work from all I've read.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

There are no errors showing up in the firebug console.  Any suggestions on how to debug or troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type-O for the dataSets property. Should be **datasets** (lowercase s).

```
datasets
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fhx55z43/3/

Comment: Thank you!  I did not spot that, and I had looked and looked.  Thank you so much for your time.